# Spring Boot logs missing using crontab command

Tags: linux, spring-boot, cron

I run my Spring Boot/Batch Jar to process large number of files in my local environment like below:

```
java -jar /path/to_my_dir_for_jar/springbatch.jar --spring.profiles.active=qa
```

And logs get generated in the same directory: `/path/to_my_dir_for_jar`

No issues whatsoever till here.

Now I ran the same job using linux crontab using (11:30 am, daily) :

```
30 11 * * * java -jar /path/to_my_dir_for_jar/springbatch.jar --spring.profiles.active=qa
```

**Please note:** I have to rely on linux crontab to schedule and not spring cron-expression as Spring Batch wont read the new files in the staging directory after first run.

Now I can NOT find my logs at - `/path/to_my_dir_for_jar`. In the application there different types of logs are generated such as:

```
service_log.gnxError.log
service_log.gcnDone.log
service_log.error.log
service_log.done.log
service_log.log
```

I tried to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log) and some other similar help but none of them seem to be working as most of them say -  `No such file or directory`

Where to look for them?

One possible way is to redirect the output of my crontab expression to a file like below:

```
30 11 * * * java -jar /path/to_my_dir_for_jar/springbatch.jar --spring.profiles.active=qa >> foobar.log
```

But this way I will loose my different type of logs as everything will be fused in just one file in this case.

Will I get the logs the way I get while running the jar manually ever using linux crontab? What are my options in this situation?

Comment: try: 30 11 * * * cd /path/to_my_dir_for_jar; java -jar /path/to_my_dir_for_jar/springbatch.jar --spring.profiles.active=qa

Comment: @FreudianSlip, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @FreudianSlip thank you very much. Inspired by your answer, this worked for me - `30 11 * * * cd /path/to_my_dir_for_jar && java -jar /path/to_my_dir_for_jar/springbatch.jar --spring.profiles.active=qa`